# Removing size column in Windows 7 Programs and Features does not stay permanently removed

Tags: windows-7

I have the problem discussed in this post:

[Win 7 Programs and Features Too Slow](https://superuser.com/questions/177082/win-7-programs-and-features-too-slow)

and in this post:

[Why does Programs and Features take minutes to populate?](https://superuser.com/questions/194093/why-does-programs-and-features-take-minutes-to-populate)

I'm trying to resolve the issue (which I've done in the past) by removing the "Size" column, as one of the answers suggests.  However, when I close and re-open "Programs and Features", the size column is back.  In fact, none of the changes I make in that window -- column order, etc. -- stick around for the next time.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: On both my machines (Windows 7 64bit Ultimate) it still works. So there must be something about the installation. Is it still working for the normal explorer window? (changing columns etc. closing and opening?)

Comment: Yes, it works in the normal explorer window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has not changed with Windows 7 and should work.

I removed a column and the following key changed in my registry:

`[HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\719\Shell\{D674391B-52D9-4E07-834E-67C98610F39D}]` namely the key `colinfo`

Looking for {D674391B-52D9-4E07-834E-67C98610F39D} in Google you can find [here](https://code.google.com/p/libfwsi/wiki/FolderTypeIdentifiers) that the FolderType for this ID is indeed "Programs" or the SoftwareExplorer.

In `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags` are normally all the changes made in all explorer windows. Maybe the `colinfo` for "Programs" is corrupt.

**Solution**: Open regedit.exe search for D674391B-52D9-4E07-834E-67C98610F39D
Ignore the foldertype entries until you come to `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\xxxx\Shell\{D674391B-52D9-4E07-834E-67C98610F39D}`. There (on the right) you can rename the underlying `colinfo` to `colinfo2` or something. When opening "Programs" Windows will create a new clean `colinfo` key and hopefully you can change the columns and Windows will remember.

Comment: Thanks Rik.  It was slightly different, but you definitely got me 95% there.  I didn't have that ID D674391B-52D9-4E07-834E-67C98610F39D anywhere in HKCU, oddly enough.  I used Sysinternals Process Monitor, as I imagine you did, to figure out exactly what had changed, and here it is:

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to submit that comment.  Here it is: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\526\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}.  That ID corresponds with the "Generic" folder type from the folder type identifiers list you posted.  I renamed the "ColInfo" value and tried the operation again, and this time it was successful.  I'd vote up your answer, but I don't have high enough rep.

Comment: I tried to use Process Monitor but it gave me too many lines (which scrolled too fast) so i used Regshot64.exe. You can click to make a snapshot of the registry, make changes, click a second time and it will give you all the changes.

Comment: Weird the key was different. Perhaps it does not need to be the same on all installations. Glad it works.